# Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Everyman\Neo4j\Exception' with message 'Unable to retrieve server info [401]:

Tags: php, neo4jphp

I just installed neo4j server in Windows and am trying to connect with php. I have xampp running, installed neo4jphp with composer, and then tried to check the connection using the following script:

```
<?php
    require('vendor/autoload.php');


    $client = new Everyman\Neo4j\Client('localhost', 7474);
    print_r($client->getServerInfo());
?>
```

Now, instead of showing server status, a fatal error occured like this:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Everyman\Neo4j\Exception' with
>   message 'Unable to retrieve server info [401]: Headers: Array ( [Date]
>   => Wed, 27 May 2015 10:54:01 GMT [Content-Type] => application/json; charset=UTF-8 [WWW-Authenticate] => None [Content-Length] => 144
>   [Server] => Jetty(9.2.z-SNAPSHOT) ) Body: Array ( [errors] => Array (
>   [0] => Array ( [message] => No authorization header supplied. [code]
>   => Neo.ClientError.Security.AuthorizationFailed ) ) ) ' in C:\xampp\htdocs\neo4j\vendor\everyman\neo4jphp\lib\Everyman\Neo4j\Command.php:116
>   Stack trace: #0
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\neo4j\vendor\everyman\neo4jphp\lib\Everyman\Neo4j\Command\GetServerInfo.php(53):
>   Everyman\Neo4j\Command->throwException('Unable to retri...', 401,
>   Array, Array) #1
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\neo4j\vendor\everyman\neo4jphp\lib\Everyman\Neo4j\Command.php(69):
>   Everyman\Neo4j\Command\GetServerInfo->handleResult(401, Array, Array)
>   #2 C:\xa in C:\xampp\htdocs\neo4j\vendor\everyman\neo4jphp\lib\Everyman\Neo4j\Command.php
>   on line 116

How to solve this?  Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: by the way neo4j is up and running with db location C:\Users\myname\Documents\Neo4j\default.graphdb  ...!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will work. You just need to define the authorization credentials, for example like this:

```
<?php
   require('vendor/autoload.php');

   $client = new Everyman\Neo4j\Client(
            (new Everyman\Neo4j\Transport\Curl('localhost',7474))
                ->setAuth('neo4j','neo4j')
   );

   print_r($client->getServerInfo());
```

Adjust the user/password accordingly('neo4j'/'neo4j' are default ones).

Another solution is to disable the requirement for authorization when accessing Neo4j. This can be done by editing Neo4j config file:

```
conf/neo4j-server.properties
```

and setting to false the following flag:

```
dbms.security.auth_enabled=false
```

Of course you need to remember about restarting the server afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

If you've installed the newest version of Neo4j, you will need authorization (provide a username and password) to connect to Neo4j. Your Everyman bundle does not seem to have one, or you are using an older one. I'm using [Neoxygen/neoclient](https://github.com/neoxygen/neo4j-neoclient) myself, which does provide the ability to provide username and password.